# Test contents of a backreference?

Tags: regex, pcre

The regex if-then-else construct allows testing if a matching group participated in a pattern:

```
(?(2)then-pattern|else-pattern)
```

I'd like to know if I can test what the backreference contains.

In my case, the backreferenced capturing group is comprised of optional sub-groups (so it always participates, but it can be empty), so testing if it is empty is sufficient, but the more general question about testing the backreference against *any* pattern is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is, yes you can test to see if the the capture group participates in the match by further sub grouping the capture with one non-optional backreference and an alternate optional backreference(which would cover the 'empty' variant).

for example:

(a)?b\1

will fail to match 'b' as \1 refers to a capture group that that failed whereas

(a)?b\1?
will match to 'b' as \1 is optional.

so the following would be a test to see if the first capture group was empty or not

(?:(a)?b\1#do first pattern|(a)?b\1?#do second pattern)

Comment: You should give example test strings- I can only make the first alternate match against "aba#do first pattern" which is not useful. Also, second alternate I think is better written as "\1?b\1?#do second pattern" and might also be helpful if "b" could be captured and backreferenced so it doesn't need to be repeated. Either way, I don't see this working, especially considering if "a" might be empty, it has to be something like "a?" which seems to foil your test. Not to mention I'm not sure it's feasible or good style to impose "b" on the match string. Do you have a working POC with test strings?

Comment: @messy I think it is you, the op, that needs to provide an example of exactly what you wish to accomplish.  The above answers the theoretical question that you asked.  If you need help with specific test strings please provide them in an edit to the original question.